# в чем ошибка реализации MarkerClusterer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Маркеры выводит, но не происходит `"Кластеризация маркеров"`

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var image = 'mapicon.png';
    function initMap(){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28.024, 140.887),
            zoom: 10        
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        var markerst = [];
        downloadUrl('function_show_map_sort_venues.php', function(data){
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem){
                var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
                var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
                var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
                var href = markerElem.getAttribute('href');
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng'))
                );

                var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');

                var strong = document.createElement('a');
                strong.setAttribute('href',href);
                strong.setAttribute('class','name_venues_maps_hos');
                strong.textContent = name;

                infowincontent.appendChild(strong);

                infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement(\'br\'));

                var text = document.createElement(\'text\');
                text.textContent = address
                infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    map: map
                });

                marker.addListener(\'click\', function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                markerst.push(marker);  
            }); 

        }); 
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerst,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject(\'Microsoft.XMLHTTP\') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };
        request.open(\'GET\', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    } 
    function doNothing() {} 
</script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBh8X_uuoOrgzfrDPee51FthH_0NOoH4VU&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: напишите вывод `console.log(markerst.length)` перед `var markerCluster`

Comment: @TotalPusher выводит `0`

Comment: Значит, вызывайте `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer ...` после загрузки точек. Конкретно - downloadUrl принимает `callback`, вот сюда и передайте `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(...`

Comment: @TotalPusher без изменений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался

```
var image = 'mapicon.png';
    function initMap(){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28.024, 140.887),
            zoom: 10        
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        var markers = [];
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
            imagePath: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m"
        });
        downloadUrl('function_show_map_sort_venues.php', function(data){
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var xmlmarkers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(xmlmarkers, function(markerElem){
                var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
                var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
                var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
                var href = markerElem.getAttribute('href');
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng'))
                );

                var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');

                var strong = document.createElement('a');
                strong.setAttribute('href',href);
                strong.setAttribute('class','name_venues_maps_hos');
                strong.textContent = name;

                infowincontent.appendChild(strong);

                infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement(\'br\'));

                var text = document.createElement(\'text\');
                text.textContent = address
                infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    map: map
                });
                marker.addListener(\'click\', function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                markers.push(marker);
                markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
            }); 
        }); 
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject(\'Microsoft.XMLHTTP\') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };
        request.open(\'GET\', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    } 
    function doNothing() {} 
</script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBh8X_uuoOrgzfrDPee51FthH_0NOoH4VU&callback=initMap"></script>
```